# How can I trigger a GitHub Workflow in a PR when a different PR is merged into the target branch?

Tags: github, github-actions

Scenario: Two PRs (A and B) are open targeting `main`. PR A is merged. I would like to re-run the tests within PR B (in the merged state pull_request events run in). Goal being to identify if any problems have arisen in B due to changes A introduced.

I've tried events such as:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, reopened, synchronize]
  push:
    branches: [main]
```

But while it will run when I push to the PR branch itself, it does not run if `main` is modified. I also tried the `pull_request_target` trigger, but it didn't seem to change anything.

At the moment, this workflow only exists with in the PR. If I try adding it to `main`, I do see a run on push, but it runs in `main`'s context and not that of the PR.

Comment: But what's the point of re-running tests for PR B? considering nothing changed in PR B. And if you want to sync changes from main, you will need to rebase/merge changes into PR B, which will trigger another round of tests.

Comment: A could've changed behavior B is relying on (or vice versa) and it would be nice to discover this before things merge into `main` without having to manually sync `main` into every open PR

Comment: If I understand correctly, perhaps a concrete example would be a migration conflict. If both PR A and B added a migration and A is merged, merging B would cause an error, even though neither A nor B showed any issues. You would only be aware of the conflict if you (rebased or) merged main into B before merging. E.g.: https://github.com/WordPress/openverse/issues/687

Comment: @hepcat72 yep that's a perfect example where the same thing would be handy